Fully qualified syntax on chained methods to avoid name collision warning
Consider the following simple rust program:
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    let my_string: String = my_vec.iter().intersperse(&' ').collect();

    println!("My string: {my_string}");
}

This code compiles but yields the following warning:
warning: a method with this name may be added to the standard library in the future
 --> src/main.rs:6:43
  |
6 |     let my_string: String = my_vec.iter().intersperse(&' ').collect();
  |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = warning: once this associated item is added to the standard library, the ambiguity may cause an error or change in behavior!
  = note: for more information, see issue #48919 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48919>
  = help: call with fully qualified syntax `itertools::Itertools::intersperse(...)` to keep using the current method
  = note: `#[warn(unstable_name_collisions)]` on by default


The compiler suggests to use a Fully Qualified Syntax to resolve this warning. I can't however figure out how to use this syntax with chained methods, as used in the example.

Try with Itertools::intersperse(my_vec.iter(), &' ').collect()?

Or you could #[allow(unstable_name_collisions)] at the risk of breakage under a future Rust version.

This works indeed, thanks! Although the resulting syntax is less clean in my opinion: It is harder the read the operations applied in a linear order. Without any other solutions I guess I'll stick with for the moment.

Yes it could be an option, but I prefer minimizing the possible origins of spontaneous breakage

An associated function with a self parameter is simply a function that takes a parameter of type Self.
In the case of the intersperse function, it takes an impl Itertools as the first parameter.
You can rewrite your code like this with the fully qualified path:
let my_string: String = itertools::Itertools::intersperse(
    my_vec.iter(), &' '
).collect();

Where you pass my_vec.iter() as the first parameter to intersperse.

Alternatively, you could create a blanket trait around this specific function to preserve the ideal readability of the original code. In a dedicated file (e.g. itersperse_wrapper.rs), place the following definition:
use itertools::Itertools;

pub trait IntersperseWrapper
where
    Self: Iterator + Sized,
    Self::Item: Clone,
{
    #[inline]
    fn itertools_intersperse(self, separator: Self::Item) -> itertools::Intersperse<Self> {
        Itertools::intersperse(self, separator)
    }
}

impl<T> IntersperseWrapper for T
where
    T: Iterator,
    T::Item: Clone,
{}


Then in your main file you can use the itertools_intersperse wrapper, preventing the warning while maintaining linear readability.
mod intersperse_wrapper;

use intersperse_wrapper::IntersperseWrapper;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    // Input vector
    let my_vec = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    // Create string using the wrapper
    let string_using_wrapper: String = my_vec
        .iter()
        .itertools_intersperse(&' ')
        .collect();

    // Create string using fully qualified syntax
    let string_using_fully_qualified_syntax: String = Itertools::intersperse(
        my_vec.iter(), &' '
        ).collect();

    assert_eq!(string_using_wrapper, "a b c d");
    assert_eq!(string_using_fully_qualified_syntax, "a b c d");
    assert_eq!(string_using_wrapper, string_using_fully_qualified_syntax);
}


This was suggested by @user459872 too. It indeed works and gets rid of the warning. However the syntax becomes less readable (the applied operations to the operator cannot be deduced with linear reading anymore). Are you aware of a workaround for this?

Yes. A possible workaround is for you to create a blanket trait (let’s say trait Intersperse), in which you define a wrapper with a different name around Itertools::intersperse, then you blanket implement this trait for every T: Itertools.

Updated my answer to reflect this.

Yes that's cleaner, I like it! It was just lacking the Sized constraint on the generic type. I submitted an edit to reflect this, as well as providing an example.

Thanks! I wrote that code on my phone so couldn’t test it :D

Though, please keep in mind, that when the intersperse function becomes a standard library feature, Itertools devs will either take it out from their library, or rename it. This code is likely to break anyway.

The OP wants "to minimize the possible causes of spontaneous breakage" - the following solution completely excludes any future breakage by using only the standard library.And yes, unfortunately Strings will be allocated.
fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    let my_string: String = my_vec
        .into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join(" ");

    println!("My string: {my_string}");
}

Playground
